# How do I use a local plugin with ParcelJS

Tags: npm, plugins, yarnpkg, parceljs

I use ParcelJS to bundle my JavaScript code. I want to modify an existing plugin (say the [Elm plugin](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/parcel-plugin-transcrypt)) to convert some special files on the fly with our own proprietary transpiler to JavaScript.

Therefor I cannot install the plugin from teh npmjs repo via Yarn into the `node_modules` folder. I have the relevant plugin files (`asset.js`, `index.js`, `package.json`) in a local directory `myplugin`. How do I tell ParcelJS to use them?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your plugin with a `package.json` in the directory `myplugin` you can add add it (as a dev dependency) with the following command:

```
yarn add ./myplugin --dev
```

Yarn will copy the plugin to the `node_modules` folder. When you have changed stuff in your plugin folder increase the version number in the plugin's `package.json` and run `yarn upgrade`.